# gRPC ECS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, grpc, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

Running a gRPC server on ECS, trying to get it to work with an application ELB however, I need SSL certs to do gRPC - I don't understand how I can create SSL certs when the hostname/common name is not something I'd have control over?

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the network load balancer I was able to get this to work